# Can I say "draw my feelings on paper"?

Tags: word-usage

Is it okay to write "draw my feelings on paper"?

The original text is "When I feel depression, I often draw my feelings on the paper and it makes me feel better."

Comment: Do you mean that you draw pictures or  patterns?

Comment: Perhaps "feel depressed" rather than "feel depression"

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly OK to say this. Some people may say that you cannot 'draw feelings', but most artists would tell you to ignore such people. In fact if you Google 'draw feelings' or 'draw emotions' you will find many articles discussing this concept.

Answer (score 1):

In English there is an often-used phrase,  **to put your feelings on paper**, which usually means to *write* about how you feel, using words.  The phrase **draw my feelings on paper** would be understood in light of that phrase, and people would think you meant making pictures, "sketching", instead of using words.